# Can you insert php into a facebook fanpage.. on any level?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I know facebook uses fbml, but curioius.. is there any way to display the results of a php script that is currently being displayed on my website?  It's only 3 little small rows of info.. but it updates dynamically and that's why I'm questioning this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the fan page is administered by you then I think the best way to do this would be to develop a custom Facebook application that does this and you could then add this application to the page.

If you're not the administrator of the page, I highly doubt that you'll be able to add this data.

Answer (score 0):

Fan pages can contain tab applications. These are scheduled to use conventional html via an iframe container this quarter, which would be able to contain the results from any site or server you wish.  At the moment, you can produce a similar result by inserting an fb:iframe into the tab applications fbml.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step by step instructions

Goto http://www.facebook.com/developers/ click on "+Set Up New App" button at top right give your application a name and create it.
Now you are on settings page. Click facebook instructions then in "Canvas URL" enter your web page URL. Then in tab sections at bottom use tab name and URL.
Don't forget to enter your "Canvas Page" name.

Answer (score -1):

Im not fammiliar with FB, but when you can use JS you can try using AJAX.

Comment: Don't post anything in answers if you don't know about it.